# Android how to use list view child in parent scroll view when scroll view child have weight

Tags: android

android how to use List view in Scroll view parent. mean when i used list view in scroll view than nothing work my list view mean not scrolling the list item. i want when the list view have multiple list item then scroll view scrolling is disable and the list view will scrolling.on my end the list view and scroll view scrolling both not working properly. and in scroll view child have also weight.

Comment: Never use a listView inside another scrollable view!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of you idea it's that Android doesn't support it.

You can use a scrollview but you need resize listview with some function like

```
public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        //do nothing return null
        return;
    }
    //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    //setting listview item in adapter
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    // print height of adapter on log
    Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
}
```

This should be work fine with 3 listviews too (I had test it with 1), but listviews won't be scrollable (full expanded), only scrollview.

It's a limit, if you scroll on listview  you lose control on scrollview, so if all are scrollable on some display resolution your app won't work fine.

The best solution for me it's use 3 fragments to show 3 listviews